# Reading Unique Values

Tags: java

I wrote a piece of code that reads values from columns in a text file. To output the number of values, I used 'length' which works fine..but I need to count only the number of unique values.

```
public class REading_Two_Files {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        readFile(new File("C:\\Users\\teiteie\\Desktop\\RECSYS\\yoochoose-test.csv"), 0,( "C:\\Users\\teiteie\\Desktop\\RECSYS\\yoochoose-buys.csv"), 3);
     //readFile(new File(File1,0, File2,3);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

////    0 - will print column from file1
    //3 - will print column from file 2

```
private static void readFile(File fin1,int whichcolumnFirstFile,String string,int whichcolumnSecondFile) throws IOException {
    //private static void readFile(File fin1,int whichcolumnFirstFile,String string,int whichcolumnSecondFile) throws IOException
    // code for this method.
    //open the two files.

    int noSessions = 0;
    int noItems = 0;
//  HashSet<String> uniqueLength = new HashSet<String>();


    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin1); //first file
    FileInputStream sec = new FileInputStream(string); // second file

//Construct BufferedReader from InputStreamReader
    BufferedReader br1= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    BufferedReader br2= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sec));

    String lineFirst = null, first_file[];
    String lineSec = null, second_file [];

    while ((lineFirst = br1.readLine()) != null && (lineSec = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        first_file= lineFirst.split(",");
        second_file = lineSec.split(",");

        //int size = data[].size();

    System.out.println(first_file[0]+" , "+second_file[0]);



    if(first_file.length != 0){
        noSessions++;
        }

        if(second_file.length != 0)  {
        noItems ++;
        }



        }

        br1.close();
        br2.close();
        System.out.println("no of sessions "+noSessions+"\nno of items "+noItems );


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To count only unique values we usually use a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as they are specified as only containing unique values.

> A collection that **contains no duplicate elements**. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

Essentially - put all of your values in a `Set` (generally a `HashSet` is the most efficient but if you want concurrency there are better options) and then take the `Set.size()` as the number of unique values you put in.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you some inspiration:

```
Map<String,Integer> lAllWordsWithCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] lAllMyStringToCount = {"Hello", "I", "am", "what", "I", "am"};
    for (String lMyString : lAllMyStringToCount) {
      int lCount = 1;
      if (lAllWordsWithCount.containsKey(lMyString)){
        lCount = lAllWordsWithCount.get(lMyString) +1;
      }
      lAllWordsWithCount.put(lMyString, lCount);
    }
    for(String lStringKey : lAllWordsWithCount.keySet()){
      System.out.println(lStringKey+" count="+lAllWordsWithCount.get(lStringKey));
    }
```

will results in:

```
what count=1
am count=2
I count=2
Hello count=1
```